# How can I write a MEMBER function using the DO macro in Common Lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am trying to make a function which works like MEMBER function in Common Lisp.
So, I want to make this function work like this :

```
(my-member 2 '(1 4 5 5 3 2 5 6 9))
=> (2 5 6 9)
```

This is exactly same as how MEMBER function works.;

```
(member 2 '(1 4 5 5 3 2 5 6 9))
=> (2 5 6 9)
```

The condition is that I should use 'DO' macro to make this function.
This is my code that I have written to make this function :

```
(defun my-member (item x)
  "This function works like MEMBER function."
  (do ((z x (rest z))                
       (e (first x) (first z)))
      (:when (equal item (first z))      
             (return z))))
```

But it doesn't work..

```
(my-member 2 '(3 4 5 2 1 1))
-> (3 4 5 2 1 1)
```

What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: MEMBER is not a macro in Lisp.

Comment: What is `:when` ?

Comment: Oops, Sorry. MEMBER is a built-in function in Lisp!

Comment: A Debugger suggested me to use that. If I don't put the semi-colon with 'when', some problems happen.

Comment: Where [in the documentation](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw60/CLHS/Body/m_do_do.htm) does it say the `end-test-form` needs to be prefixed with a `:when` or a `when`? Are you sure this is Common Lisp?

Comment: @Sylwester I am using Allegro CL express edition to debug. This program suggested me to do that when I tried to debug the file. I could do debug by doing that. Yep! This is common lisp. That makes me confused because  I have never learned that I should put ':' in frony of when or if. If I don't put it, I got this type og error message when I debug : WHEN is Unbound variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the correct way to use `do`:

```
(do ((var 0 (1+ var))
     (lst '() (cons var lst)))
    ((= var 5) lst)))
; ==> (4 3 2 1 0)
```

So both `var` and `lst` are variables initialised to `0` and `()` and after each iteration the variable is set to `(1+ var)` and `(cons var lst)`.

What determines when it should stop is `(= var 5)` becoming not nil and when that happens the result of the whole `do` form is `lst`. This is the second part of the `do` and the last this has since I do not supply a body.

You can make an equivalent of the `member` **function** with using only one variable and a second part with an end condition and what should be the result of the `do`. Good luck!